# How to center text in bootstrap 3 progress bar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a progress bar, using Bootstrap 3, with the following code:

```
   <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 60%;">
        </div>
        <span>60%</span>
    </div>
```

Screenshot of output:

[image: screenshot]

However, this causes the text '60%' to be displayed towards the right, rather than in the center of the progress bar. How can I center this text, so it appears in the center?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would put a class on the span tag, and put the tag before the progress-bar class.  Then set the span to `position:absolute` and give progress `text-align:center`:

HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
    <span class="progress-value">60%</span>
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
    text-align:center;
}
.progress-value {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/fSLdG/2/

Comment: For whatever reason, I keep preferring to define right and left, as opposed to width...  Thanks @Ruddy

Comment: Both work, feel free to use my demo in your answer. Just adds another option. Good job.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to @bozdoz answer:

Absolutely positioning the progress percentage indicator will do the trick:

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 60%;">
    </div>
    <span>60%</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.progress {
    position:relative;
}
.progress span {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:2;
    color:white;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/ejgp5/

Answer (score 1):

Twitter's bootstrap `.span` classes are floated to the left. Try adding `float:none` to the span it might work!

```
.progress span{
   margin: 0px auto;
   float:none;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
This works for sure: HTML

```
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 60%;"></div>
  <span>60%</span>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .progress {
    position: relative;
 }

 .bar {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
  }

 .progress span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.progress{ border: 5px solid;}
.progress-bar{background: #369;line-height: 50px;display: inline-block;}
.progress span{display: block; margin: 0px auto; width: 40px; margin-top: -50px; line-height: 50px; color: #fff;}
```

Comment: Sorry I have added wrong link.. Please check the following http://jsfiddle.net/VpfkM/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this out i used the `<center> </center>` tag i am not sure about backward compatibility but i have tested in chrome and Mozilla Firefox and there are current.

sample code (doesn't need any CSS):

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active" style="margin:0 10%;display:none;" id="uploadProgressbar">
        <center><b><span class="progress-value" id="uploadProgressValue" style="color:red;">00%</span> </b></center>
             <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" id="uploadProgress" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">

             </div>
</div>
```